# Double clicking a element in robotframework throws error "move target out of bounds" while clicking works fine

Tags: robotframework

I was double click an element. That was inside a table, and on double click it will open a popup grid in webpage, where we can select a value for that field. I was able to  click, Input text, but unable to double click. It was throwing MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds error
Also tried with actions
This was the element inspected:-

please help to resolve this

Comment: Please, add your codes.

Comment: Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id="ml1"]
    Set focus to element    xpath=//*[@id="ml1"]
    Double Click Element    xpath=//*[@id="ml1"]Using actions this was the code I used                                                                                     def double_click_using_xpath(driver,id):
 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(id)
 actions = ActionChains(driver)
 actions.double_click(elem).perform()

Comment: @SubalakshmiRavichandran please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly to get more answers